# Why is unicode not working in my MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, html, unicode

I have a MySQL DB table where I store addresses, including Norwegain addresses.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `addresses` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `street1` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `street2` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT 'NULL',
  `zipcode` varchar(10) COLLATE NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_store` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_danish_ci;
```

Now, this table was fine untill I screwed up and accidentaly set all cities = 'test'. Luckilly I had another table called `helper_zipcode`. This table contains alle zipcodes and cities for Norway.

So I updated `addresses` table with data from `helper_zipcode`.

Unfortunately in the front end, cities like `Bodø` now shows like `Bod�`.
All `æ ø å`are now shown as `� � �` (but they look fine in the DB).

I'm using HTML 5, so my header looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <head> 
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
  (...)
```

This is not the first time I struggle with unicode.

What is the seceret for storing unicode characters (from Europe) in DB and display the same way when retrieved from DB?

Comment: what is the charset of the `helper_zipcode` table?

Comment: Just out of interest, what happens if you change your browser encoding from auto-detect to UTF-8 or Unicode ? Trying to determine if its the Database or the Web-browser that's wrong.

Comment: `SET NAMES utf8;` (or `mysql_set_charset()` or whatever your database library has  to offer to define the connection's character set) is probably it.

Comment: @Russ C - there was no difference. So it's not a browser problem.

Comment: @Spudley, before I changed it, it was set to `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;` Now I've changed it to `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_danish_ci;`. But even if I change city name through a MySQL manager app (`Toad for MySQL`), I still get the weird boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from mysql [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-unicode.html):

> Posted by lorenz pressler on May 2
>   2006 12:46pm  [Delete] [Edit]
>
> if you
>   get data via php from your mysql-db
>   (everything utf-8)  but still get '?'
>   for some special characters in your
>   browser  (`<meta
>   http-equiv="Content-Type"
>   content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
>   />`),  try this:
>
> after `mysql_connect()` , and
>   `mysql_select_db()` add this lines: 
>   `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");`
>
> worked for me. i tried first with the
>   `utf8_encode`, but this only worked for
>   äüöéè...  and so on, but not for
>   kyrillic and other chars.

Is your problem storing the data in mysql or from retrieving the stored data using php?

Comment: That actually did it. I Added this to my PDO connection `array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")`. I laso had to upgrade to php v5.3 since there is a bug in earlier version preventing me from using this.

Answer (score 1):

Before query (1-st time) you must need add mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change your browser encoding from auto-detect to UTF-8 or Unicode ?

What I'm trying to determine if its the Database or the Web-browser that's wrong.

Alternatively. if you have a Database tool for your MySQL database, does that show the right or wrong characters ?

Comment: There is not data type called `NVARCHAR`. The only refernce I find is thishttp://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html. So where do I do this?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I misread the question and though it was SQL server.